# Which code in LLVM IR runs before "main()"?

Tags: linux, llvm, elf, llvm-ir, ldd

Does anyone know the general rule for exactly which LLVM IR code will be executed before `main`?

When using Clang++ 3.6, it seems that global class variables have their constructors called via a function in the ".text.startup" section of the object file.  For example:

```
define internal void @__cxx_global_var_init() section ".text.startup" {
  call void @_ZN7MyClassC2Ev(%class.MyClass* @M)
  ret void
}
```

From this example, I'd guess that I should be looking for exactly those IR function definitions that specify `section ".text.startup"`.

I have two reasons to suspect my theory is correct:

- I don't see anything else in my LLVM IR file (`.ll)` suggesting that the global object constructors should be run first, if we assume that LLVM isn't sniffing for C++ -specific function names like "__cxx_global_var_init".  So `section ".text.startup"` is the only obvious means of saying that code should run before `main()`.  But even if that's correct, we've identified a *sufficient* condition for causing a function to run before `main()`, but haven't shown that it's the only way in LLVM IR to cause a function to run before `main()`.
- The Gnu linker, [in some cases](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_24.html), will use the first instruction in the `.text` section to be the program entry point.  [This article](http://www.valvers.com/open-software/raspberry-pi/step02-bare-metal-programming-in-c-pt2/) on Raspberry Pi programming describes causing the `.text.startup` content to be the first body of code appearing in the program's `.text` section, as a means of causing the `.text.startup` code to run first.

Unfortunately I'm not finding much else to support my theory:

- When I grep the LLVM 3.6 source code for the string ".startup", I only find it in the CLang-specific parts of the LLVM code.  For my theory to be correct, I would expect to have found that string in other parts of the LLVM code as well; in particular, parts outside of the C++ front-end.
- This article on [data initialization in C++](http://woboq.com/blog/data-and-initialisation.html) seems to hint at ".text.startup" having a special role, but it doesn't come right out and say that the Linux program loader actually looks for a section of that name.  Even if it did, I'd be surprised to find a potentially Linux-specific section name carrying special meaning in platform-neutral LLVM IR.
- The Linux 3.13.0 source code doesn't seem to contain the string ".startup", suggesting to me that the program loader isn't sniffing for a section with the name ".text.startup".

Comment: UPDATE: It turns out the global c'tor execution was probably caused by the presence of [`@llvm.global_ctors` global variable](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#the-llvm-global-ctors-global-variable) in that IR code.

That does leave two open questions though: (1) why does clang _also_ specify `section ".text.startup"`?  And (2), are there also, other ways IR code can indicate that it should be run before `main()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is pretty easy - LLVM is not executing anything behind the scenes. It's a job of the C [runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_library) (CRT) to perform all necessary preparations before running main(). This includes (but not limited to) to static ctors and similar things. The runtime is usually informed about these objects via addresses of constructores being emitted in the special sections (e.g. .init_array or .ctors). See e.g. http://wiki.osdev.org/Calling_Global_Constructors for more information.